# Register Helpers in MVC4 with AutoFac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I need to avoid parameters to create an Helper so I use AutoFac, but I'm not able to do it:

```
public class PTDistrictHelpers
{
    private readonly IPTDistrictService _ptDistrictService;

    public PTDistrictHelpers(IPTDistrictService ptDistrictService)
    {
        _ptDistrictService = ptDistrictService;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropDownList(int selectedValue = GlobalConstants.DROPDOWNLIST_NO_SELECTED_VALUE)
    {
        var ptDistrictsDto = _ptDistrictService.ListAll();
        var ptDistrictsViewModel = Mapper.Map<IList<PTDistrictDto>, IList<PTDistrictViewModel>>(ptDistrictsDto);

        var ptDistrictsList = ptDistrictsViewModel.Select(district =>
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = district.Id.ToString(),
                Text = district.Name,
                Selected = (district.Id == selectedValue)
            });

        return ptDistrictsList;
    }
}
```

In the AutoFac Config I have:

```
public class AutofacConfig
{
    public static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // PTDistrict Helpers
        builder.RegisterType<PTDistrictHelpers>()
            .As<PTDistrictHelpers>()
            .InstancePerHttpRequest();

        // PTDistrict Interface registration
        builder.RegisterType<PTDistrictService>()
            .As<IPTDistrictService>()
            .InstancePerHttpRequest();
     }
 }
```

In the Controller when I try to create a new PTDistrictHelpers I get the error "does not contain a constructor that takes 0 argument".

```
var ptDistrictList = new PTDistrictHelpers().DropDownList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere you also need to register an `IPTDistrictService` so Autofac can populate the helper constructor.

I don't know if you're really trying to new-up a helper or if that's just for example, but the helper class you posted doesn't have a no-parameter constructor so that last code snippet wouldn't compile.

Your controller should take in a helper class as a constructor parameter and let Autofac do the work.

Comment: Hi thanks, let me see if I understand your answer (I have completed the question with the AutoFac PTDistrictService registration). I register the helper, and should I put it in the Controller constructor also? Or should I call create it with a new PTDistrictHelpers(); instance? I tested and I'm not able to access the methods :(

Comment: The point of IoC is that you don't "new" anything yourself, you pass it in as a dependency. Register all the moving pieces with Autofac. Pass the helper into the controller as a constructor parameter. When Autofac resolves your controller through the MVC dependency resolver, everything will get wired up automatically. It might be worth checking out the Autofac wiki for examples. https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki

Comment: Hi, I think I understand your comment, I tried to declare the Helper class in the Controller's constructor and it's working fine. In your opinion, should I pass the ptDistrictsDto by parameter to the Helper's method or should I call the service from the Helper?

Comment: I'm not sure I have enough context within your project to answer that. However, your original question is answered and, as you said, things are working. Given that's the case, could you mark this as the answer? If you want more discussion on how to use Autofac in general, the Autofac Google Group is a great place for that.

Comment: Thanks, I have marked the answer as correct but I will put my code to explain to others how I put it to work. My last question was more related with a best practice context, op1 make the call to the Business Layer to populate the Dropdown in the Helper, or op2 I pass the data from the Controller to the helper containing the list of values and build the dropdown inside the helper with a parameters list, what do you think?

Comment: I think it's a great discussion topic for the Google Group.

Comment: And what is your opinion about it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer (personal opinion) is: it depends. If you have a lot of instances of "call this exact service thing and make a dropdown list out of it," then it might be worth keeping it in the helper and calling the helper from the controller. If you, instead, have a lot of different data and you just need something that makes dropdowns out of it, then getting the data in the controller and passing to the helper makes sense.

Comment: Given a guess at what else might be in the "helpers" class, though: I'm a fan of the Single Responsibility Principle and I hate classes that are called "Helper" or "Utility" because they invariably become dumping grounds for unrelated "I didn't know where else to put this" stuff. I'd consider renaming to "DistrictDropdownGenerator" if you keep that helper. That way it doesn't start generating dropdowns for other controllers or data. **If you'd like to talk more, please visit us on the Autofac discussion group.** I don't mean to sound unhelpful but we're a bit beyond the original question.